# HighCharts graphs are not showing in IE

Tags: internet-explorer-8, highcharts

For me Highcharts graphs are not showing in Internet Explorer. I searched and saw that extra comma might be a problem but I don't find extra comma in my script.

Following fiddle showing highcharts initialization part only.

```
 var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
        chart: {
            renderTo: 'container'
        },
        credits: {
            text: 'Reference: WHO Child Growth Standards (Birth-2 years in percentiles).'
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24],
            gridLineWidth: 1,
            gridLineColor: 'lightgray',
            gridLineDashStyle: 'longdash',
            title: {
                text: 'Age (Completed months and years)'
            }
        },
        yAxis: {
            gridLineWidth: 1,
            gridLineColor: 'lightgray',
            gridLineDashStyle: 'longdash',
            title: {
                text: 'Length (cm)'
            },

            tickInterval: 5,
            allowDecimals: false,
            min: 45,
            max: 95
        },
        plotOptions: {
            spline: {
                marker: {
                    radius: 0,
                    lineColor: '#666666',
                    lineWidth: 1
                }
            }
        },
        legend: {
            layout: 'vertical',
            align: 'right',
            verticalAlign: 'top',
            borderWidth: 0,
            reversed: true,
            y: 30,
            width: 200,
            itemMarginTop: 6,
            itemMarginBottom: 6
        },
        exporting: {`enter code here`
            enabled: false
        }
    });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/aparnaunny/RzyY8/

Comment: This examples doenst work in any browser, I adivce to use console (developer tools in chrome/ff) and fix all bugs which you have like "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token else "

Comment: I have updated jsfiddle. Please check now.http://jsfiddle.net/aparnaunny/RzyY8/1/

Answer (score 1):

The problem I found is the version of jQuery, which for some reason makes errors on INternet Explorer.
Try an older version, e.g. jQuery 1.9.1
For me that worked

http://jsfiddle.net/RzyY8/2/

```
jQuery 1.9.1
```

Comment: I have updated my jsfiddle. I'm sorry i just copied part of my code. Please refer to this http://jsfiddle.net/aparnaunny/RzyY8/1/

Comment: Actually also a newer version of jQuery worked. just 1.10.1 does not!

Comment: Finally! Got it. indexOf supported in IE 9+. Thanks all for your help.

Answer (score 0):

In gerenal you should run jsfiddle.net/aparnaunny/RzyY8/1/show because fiddles are not supported by ie8. Secondly run your console in the ie8, and you will see that the prbolem is in the line 361.

```
if(age==2.0)
{
    $("#median").append('Median height for this age is 87.1161 cm');
    ind=malearr24.indexOf(height);
    if(ind=='-1')
    {
```